# In Celery how to update the state of a main task until all his subtasks are done?

Tags: python, django, celery

In Celery I'm running a main task that run one subtask for each item it get from the query. Subtasks should run in parallel. On the UI I have a progress bar that show how many subtasks are done on the total. I'm updating the main task state to give the info to the progress bar. My problem is that the main task ended right after pushing all the subtasks to the broker so I can't update his state anymore. I wish that the main task could wait until all the subtasks were done. Is it possible? Any other solutions? Here's my pseudo code (real code don't use global ;-)).

```
total = 0
done = 0

@task(ignore_result=True)
def copy_media(path):
    global total, done
    copy_media.update_state(state=STARTED, meta={'total': total, 'done': done})
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    total = documents.count()
    copy_media.update_state(state=STARTED, meta={'total': total, 'done': done})
    for document in documents:
        process_doc.delay(document, path, copy_media)

@task(ignore_result=True)
def process_doc(document, path, copy_media):
    global total, done
    # Do some stuff
    done += 1
    copy_media.update_state(state=STARTED, meta={'total': total, 'done': done})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way using `TaskSet`. But I'm not totally satisfied because I can't ignore the result of the subtasks. If I ignore result for the `process_doc` task `results.ready()` always return `False`, `results.completed_count()` always return 0, etc. Here's the code:

```
@task(ignore_result=True)
def copy_media(path):
    copy_media.update_state(state=STARTED, meta={'total': total, 'done': done})
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    total = documents.count()
    copy_media.update_state(state=STARTED, meta={'total': total, 'done': done})
    job = TaskSet(tasks=[process_doc.subtask((document, path))
                         for document in documents])
    results = job.apply_async()
    doc_name = ''
    while not results.ready():
        done = results.completed_count()
        if done:
            last = done - 1
            for idx in xrange(last, -1, -1):
                if results[idx].ready():
                    doc_name = results[idx].result
                    break
        copy_media.update_state(state=STARTED, meta={'total': total, 'done': done, 'doc-name': doc_name})
        time.sleep(0.25)

@task()
def process_doc(document, path):
    # Do some stuff
    return document
```

Comment: As the documentation clearly states: "Having a task wait for the result of another task is really inefficient, and may even cause a deadlock if the worker pool is exhausted.
Make your design asynchronous instead, for example by using callbacks." http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks

Comment: My main task `copy_media` is not waiting for the result of another task. It's continuously  updating the state to show how many subtasks are done, etc. And subtasks are running in parallel so callback here is not an option. On top of that I can't have deadlocks because `copy_media` can be run only one at a time, so it's just blocking 1 worker.

Comment: That's effectively waiting the results of another tasks. You're calling results.ready(), and there's one task testing others. If your workers are exhausted, you have a deadlock, as none of the subtasks will get executed, and your main task will never finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcached-backed caching to store number of complete tasks.  There's even `cache.inrc` in django cache API for atomic increment to make sure concurrent updates of count don't screw things up.

Also, holding main task running until all subtasks complete is bad idea because you're basically blocking one of celery workers for a long time.  If celery is run with one worker process, this will result in never-ending lock.

Comment: About your suggestion to using the Django cache to store the count, I find it strange to have to re-implement something that's already there in Celery, ie. a state system. And my needs are more complex then only keeping the count. As you can see in my answer, I'm also passing the document name (and more stuff in the real project). For the fact that my main task is blocking a Celery worker, I can see the problem but it's definitely not a problem in my case. I have a dedicated Celery daemon for this main task and subtasks with many workers and I'm preventing the main task to run concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which version of celery you are running but you could have a look at [Group](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) subtasks (new in 3.0).